# Mouse click only works once with iterm2/tmux/mosh

Tags: macos, vim, mouse, tmux, iterm2

I'm trying to set up iTerm2 + mosh + tmux to do my remote work. I can get everything to connect up, but for some reason, the mouse response is funky. If I split my tmux window so I have two panes and click to switch between them, the first time I do this, everything is find. The second time and thereafter, it doesn't work at all. I can't scroll or do anything else mouse related either. This only happens after I click. If all I do is scroll in the two windows, no problem.

The problem doesn't come up if I use SSH instead of mosh, but the whole point of this attempt was to switch over to mosh full-time. The problem also doesn't happen if I don't use tmux and just have a single vim window. I can click around in there all day.

Does anyone know what setting could be wrong or even where to start? It's obviously related to tmux, but I haven't been able to find a setting that could be causing the problem.

#### tmux.conf

```
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D

set -g mode-mouse on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on
```

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to dig into about Mosh and it's outlandish arrogant claims of superior security over OpenSSH. Everything is secure until a hole is found.

"iTerm2 is integrated with tmux, allowing you to enjoy a native user interface with all the benefits of tmux's persistence."

https://iterm2.com/documentation-tmux-integration.html

***Limitations***

"There are a few limitations of tmux integration which are related to the design of tmux.

- A tab with a tmux window may not contain non-tmux split panes.
- A tab with split panes may have "empty" areas. This is because tmux
  wants every tmux window to be the same size, but our split pane
  dividers are not exactly one cell by one cell in size."

---

***MOSH***    https://mosh.org/

"Mosh is a command-line program, like ssh. You can use it inside xterm, gnome-terminal, urxvt, Terminal.app, iTerm, emacs, screen, or **tmux**. But mosh was designed from scratch and **supports just one character set: UTF-8.** It fixes Unicode bugs in other terminals and in SSH."

**Q:** *Why is my terminal's scrollback buffer incomplete?*

- Mosh synchronizes only the visible state of the terminal. We are tracking this issue; see this issue and the others which are linked from there. For now, the workaround is to ***use screen or tmux on the remote side.***

**Q:**  *How does Mosh's security compare with SSH's?*

... The answer to this little jewel of a question leaves a Lot of room for heated debate and possibly another answer to why you are getting "funky" response.

"~ By contrast, **Mosh applies its security at a different layer** (authenticating every datagram), ~"

"However, in typical usage, Mosh relies on SSH to exchange keys *at the beginning of a session*, so Mosh will inherit the **weaknesses (?!)** of SSH—at least insofar as they affect the ***brief SSH session*** that is used to set up a long-running Mosh session."

Hmmm, one has to wonder if SSH is so weak and inferior to Mosh's way of doing things, then why does Mosh initiate with SSH?

Personal Opinion: I would steer clear of mosh.